# the difference between if and cond?

Tags: scheme, sicp

i'm learning sicp now and do the ex2.23
i have wrirten the following code:

```
(define (for-each proc items)
   (if (null? items)
       #t
       ((proc (car items))
        (for-each proc (cdr items)))))
```

but when running, cause error: **procedure application: expected procedure, given: #; arguments were: ()**

i think i know the reason: I call the for-each function recursively, every called for-each wanted to return value

but when i have modified the code:

```
(define (for-each proc items)
  (cond ((null? items) #t)
        (else (proc (car items)) (for-each proc (cdr items)))))
```

it runs well. I don't understand, why? in **cond**, does every called for-each no need to return value?

i used DrScheme, and choose language [SICP](http://www.neilvandyke.org/sicp-plt/)

i'm not a native speaker of english, so if there is sth which isn't described clearly, pls tell me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> but when running, cause error: procedure application: expected > procedure, given: #; arguments were: ()
>
> i think i know the reason: I call the for-each function recursively, > every called for-each wanted to return value

No, it is because in the alternative clause of `if` you have the combination `((proc (car items)) (for-each proc (cdr items)))`. You intended to evaluate the two combinations `(proc (car items))` and `(for-each proc (cdr items))` sequentially, and to that end you thought putting them in another pair of parentheses would work.  But in actuality, what you have specified is that the result of `(proc (car items))` is a procedure to be applied to the argument which is the return value of `(for-each proc (cdr items))`. This is not the case, and you get an error.  The key point being that parentheses in Lisp are not for grouping, but have a definite significance.

The problem is that `if` can only have a single combination in that position, whereas you want to have two in a row. On the other hand, `cond` does not suffer such a restriction; you can put as long a sequence of individual combinations in the consequent part of a `cond` clause as your heart desires. This state of affairs is simply how the language is defined to work.

You can just as well use `cond` in these situations, but if you still want to use `if` there are some options for stuffing multiple combinations into one.  E. g. you can create a lambda procedure whose body is the two combinations and immediately fire it off:

```
(define (for-each proc items)
   (if (null? items)
       #t
       ((lambda ()
          (proc (car items))
          (for-each proc (cdr items)) )) ))
```

Or you can use `begin` which is actually meant to be used for such a purpose:

```
(define (for-each proc items)
   (if (null? items)
       #t
       (begin
          (proc (car items))
          (for-each proc (cdr items)) ) ))
```

Comment: `begin` is the proper thing to do if you want to evaluate multiple statements in an `if` clause